# flatlist (React native) scrolls to top when new item is added to redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a problem updating the store. When I add an element to it, my flatlist scrolls to the very top, but I wouldn't like that. How can I solve this problem?

my code (book.tsx)

```
export const NewBook = () => {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const datanewBook = useSelector((state:ReduxType) => state.newBook);

const updateData = () => dispatch((fetchDataNewBookUpdate(datanewBook.data.next) as any));

const DataNewBook = () => {

    if(datanewBook.data && !datanewBook.load)

        return  <NewBookContainer>
                    <FlatList
                        refreshing={datanewBook.load}
                        keyExtractor={(element) => element.title}
                        ListHeaderComponent={<PopularBook/>}
                        data={datanewBook.data.results}
                        snapToInterval={200}
                        renderItem={(book) => NewBookCard(book)}
                        onEndReached={updateData}
                    />
                </NewBookContainer>

        return  <LoadingComponent/>

}

return  <DataNewBook/>
```

}

code that is responsible for the update logic (store.tsx):

```
export const fetchDataNewBookUpdate = (link: string) => {

const book_default = {
    load: true,
    data: {
        count: 0,
        next: '',
        previous: null,
        results:  null
    }
}

return (dispatch:any) => {
    console.log(link)

    fetch(link)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(UpdateDataNew({load: false, data: (json as Book)})))
    .catch(() => dispatch(UpdateDataNew(book_default)));

}
```

}

the code that is responsible for the update logic of store redux (asyncData.tsx):

```
    import { Book, ResultsEntity } from '../../interface/interface';

const defatult_state:{load:boolean, data: Book} = {

    load: true,
    data: {
        count: 0,
        next: '',
        previous: null,
        results:  null
    }

}

export const newBook = (state = defatult_state, action: {type: string, payload:{load:boolean, data: Book}}) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'LOAD_DATA_NEW':
            return {...state, ...action.payload}
        case 'UPDATE_DATA_NEW':
            return {load: action.payload.load, data: {count: action.payload.data.count, next: action.payload.data.next, results: [...(state.data.results as ResultsEntity[]), ...(action.payload.data.results as ResultsEntity[])]}}
        default:
            return state

    }

}

export const LoadDataNew = (payload:{load:boolean, data: Book}) => ({type: 'LOAD_DATA_NEW', payload});
export const UpdateDataNew = (payload:{load:boolean, data: Book}) => ({type: 'UPDATE_DATA_NEW', payload});
```

Answer (score -4):

I'm just an idiot. The solution to the problem was simple...

maybe it will help a non-observant person like me

```
    export const NewBook = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const datanewBook = useSelector((state:ReduxType) => state.newBook);

    const updateData = () => dispatch((fetchDataNewBookUpdate(datanewBook.data.next) as any));

    return  <NewBookContainer>
                <FlatList
                    keyExtractor={(element) => element.id.toString()}
                    ListHeaderComponent={<PopularBook/>}
                    ListFooterComponent={<LoadingComponent/>}
                    data={datanewBook.data.results}
                    snapToInterval={200}
                    renderItem={(book) => NewBookCard(book)}
                    onEndReached={updateData}
                />
            </NewBookContainer>

}
```

Comment: Please update your answer to clearly indicate what the issue was. Your answer as-is is not helpful to the reader. It is not obvious.